# Electrostatic self-interaction of two multivariate Gaussian charge densities

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, charge, integration, quantum-chemistry

I'm trying to figure out the following question:

If $\mathcal{N_1}(\vec x|\vec \mu_1, \Sigma_1)$ and $\mathcal{N_2}(\vec x|\vec \mu_2, \Sigma_2)$ are two arbitrary multivariate Gaussian charge densities with means $\vec \mu_i$ and covariance matrices $\Sigma_i$, is there a closed form expression for their electrostatic interaction
\begin{equation}
\iint \frac{\mathcal{N_1}(\vec x|\vec \mu_1, \Sigma_1) \mathcal{N_2}(\vec x'|\vec \mu_2, \Sigma_2)}{|\vec x - \vec x'|} d^3\vec x d^3\vec x'
\end{equation}
in terms of the means and covariance matrices?

The somewhat closest answer I could find is expression (2) given by [Chialvo and Cummings (1998)](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.499.1210&rep=rep1&type=pdf). They assume, however, that the covariance matrices are a multiple of the identity (i.e. radially symmetric Gaussians).

I find it hard to imagine there is no closed-form expression for such a simple extension of the problem, yet I also feel stuck in how to approach it.
Perhaps it is easier to first derive an analytic solution to the Poisson equation with multivariate Gaussian charge?

Thanks, all help is appreciated.

Comment: I assume you've already tracked down the subsequent reference [23] from the same authors?  I'd check it to be sure they don't treat the more general case in that work.

Comment: covariance matrices are always diagonalizable, so is it just a special choice of co-ordinate system to choose it diagonal?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I've looked for other papers by these two authors from the same and the following years, but was unable to find one they were likely referring to (note the reference just states the authors and 'in preparation').

Comment: @CWPP I've originally been thinking along these lines as well... but unfortunatlely, whenever the eigenvectors of the covariance matrix have different norms, choosing diagonalizing coordinates will ruin the radial symmetry of the Coulomb 1/r profile... so whichever frame you choose, either the covariance matrix or the Coulomb potential does not have the form you'd like it to have.

Comment: Also, this is perhaps a minor note, but I've had a mistake in my question – in the paper I've linked, they don't just assume the covariance matrix is diagonal, but that it's a multiple of the identity, i.e. they just talk about radially symmetric gaussians (edited this to be correct now). This links to my comment before: in this case, you can just go to spherical coordinates,  in which the angle part integrates out after which you can evaluate the radial part analytically.